# Post/Create a poll using Yammer REST API

Tags: javascript, api, rest, yammer

I have been working on a project where there is a requirement to develop a custom web part that displays the feeds from Yammer. Also, the logged in user should be able to post messages, attachments, polls from the web part.

I was able to post messages and attachments using rest api and with yammer embed. But I couldn't find any information/documentation on how to post/create a poll via Yammer API using JavaScript. I've browsed through the documentation provided by Yammer( https://developer.yammer.com/documentation/ ) and googled a lot, but couldn't get any help.

Any suggestions regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Srivikas Nallamilli.

Answer (score 3):

Use the same API that you use to fetch messages from yammer i.e https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json

When you post a poll, above api will return json respose something as below:

```html
"external_references":[],
   "meta":{  
      "requested_poll_interval":60,
      "realtime":{  
         "uri":"https://7-791.rt.yammer.com/cometd/",
         "authentication_token":<TOKEN>
         "channel_id":<CHANNEL ID>
      },
      "last_seen_message_id":null,
      "current_user_id":1530316230,
      "followed_references":[  

      ],
      "ymodules":[  
         {  
            "id":12147685,
            "inline_html":"<INLINE HTML>",
            "viewer_id":1530316230
         }
      ],
      "newest_message_details":null,
      "feed_name":"Company Feed",
      "feed_desc":"",
      "direct_from_body":false
   }
```

you will get the poll message in inline html section highlighted in code above.

Let me know if it works.

Thanks,

Avni Bhatt